# Do I get the meaning correctly?

Tags: meaning

I've just read an article about GM food. I can't get the following sentence:

> Should those against this bill lose the label war, they might be able to turn to Clear Labs technology to get a better idea of what is in that package of ramen or can of corn on the shelf at their local grocery store.
>   <sup>[source](http://techcrunch.com/2015/09/15/clear-labs-aims-to-be-google-search-for-gmos-in-our-packaged-food/#.n1eslf:PcCS)</sup>

Does that mean that if the opponents of the bill lose this war, they still should have the right to turn to Clear Labs to know the product contents?

Comment: There is nothing about any "right" in the original text.

Comment: Yes, I guess they mean the opportunity, don't they?

Comment: You can read the opening "should" as "if" or "in the event that."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you understood it pretty well.

If they lose stopping that bill(if they are unable to stop the bill), then people may have the opportunity to have Clear Labs provide that information.

Comment: Your sentence is harder to understand than the original.